# Could I use result of variable as array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Can I use variables value to initialize an array in Java?

I have read about array in stackoverflow but I still not understand yet. Arrays in Java always use fixed size in curly braces {} symbol. Can I use the value of variable in curly braces {}  symbol like this :

```
Integer lat = (int) (location.y/(mapheight/180)-90)-1; --> This is that variables
Integer lng = (int) location.x/(mapwidth/360)-180;
try {
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("Latitude");
  sb.append(',');
  sb.append("Longitude");
  sb.append('\n');

  int count = 1;
  Integer[] lat_value = new Integer[]{lat}; ---> This is what I talked about...
  while (count < faceDetections.toArray().length) {
    sb.append(lat_value[count]);
    sb.append(',');
    sb.append(lng);
    sb.append('\n');
    count++;
  }
  pw.write(sb.toString());
  pw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope somebody can help me because I have tried it for 4 days but I still not understand yet. Sorry for my bad english :( . Thank You

NB : I think I make all people be confused. I just want to save output to an array then write to a .csv file. I hope it makes clear to all of you :( . You can review my code in [here](http://ideone.com/7Loz5o)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But I am not sure what your goal is. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Agree with @AndrewEisenberg -- I have no idea what you're asking and how it relates to your code. Please clarify your question AND your code.

Comment: It is perfectly legal, so if the compiler does not complain you are fine. See this [DEMO](http://ideone.com/FWu2ht)

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg  : Actually I wanna create csv file and save that result of longitude and latitude in that csv. Am I right if I use array to save that result in csv file?. Because what I know is the result of longitude and latitude is more than one value. Example latitude = {120,270,...}. I am really sorry if I explain my goal in wrong words because English is not my main language :(. I hope all of you could understand what I explain. I really need your help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I wanna save the result of longitude and latitude. Example like this : Longitude = [120,270,...]. And then I want to save the result of Longitude in csv. That's why I am using array and looping. Am I right?. I hope u could understand what I explain. Sorry for bad English :(

Comment: @MaxZoom : I am getting error message "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" when I use it in my coding :(

Comment: @JEKAS can you check/print value of `lat` ?

Comment: @MaxZoom : Yes, I already print it using System.out.println("Latitude : "+lat). And the result is : Latitude -46
Latitude -45
Latitude 7. And I want to save that result in csv but it doesn't works :( . I have modified it and using your code before but I get error message "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Comment: It's very unclear what your question or problem is. If you have a compile or runtime error, edit your question to include it, with a stack trace if possible.

Comment: @shmosel : I am trying to explain what is my code problem but people can't understand what I explain because my English is bad :( . I just want to save my longitude and latitude in csv using array and looping. Just it :(. I hope u can help me :(.

Comment: @JEKAS it seems to be not related to the array initialization. I would advise you to comment your code below that line and see if it still has an issue.

Comment: @MaxZoom : Do you mean I have to copy full of my code in here?. I follow your step to view code in ideone.com. So I copy my full coding in  here -> [link](http://ideone.com/7Loz5o). I give mark in ideone.com with //Arrays still getting error. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @All : Could all of you help me? I really need your help so much :( . I am beginner in Java and dont let me stuck on this code. Please :'(

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As shown in the *Creating, Initializing, and Accessing* part of this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Example of *shortcut syntax*:

```
Integer[] initial = { 127, Integer.valueOf( 42 ) };
```

Which could also be done like this:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf( 42 );
Integer[] initial = { 127, i};
```